# if (isset($_POST["submit"]))

Tags: php, session, post

I am a completely new programmer and I am trying to develop a website in php. All I want to do in this part of the code is to "read" the user's inputs and save them as session variables in order to do/ calculate something else in another subpage. In order to see if everything is working fine I added the lines `echo "Welcome ",$_SESSION["firstname"];` `echo "ok"` but it is not working. Can you help me? 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
        <b>First Name:</b> <input name="firstname" type="text" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Last Name:</b>  <input name="lastname" type="text" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Age:</b> <input name="age" type="number" min="0" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Number of people in household:</b> <input name="numberofpeopleinhousehold" type="number" min="1"value=""></br></br>

        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form

<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$_SESSION["firstname"]= $_POST["firstname"];
$_SESSION["lastname"]= $_POST["lastname"];
$_SESSION["age"]= $_POST["age"];
$_SESSION["numberofpeopleinhousehold"]= $_POST["numberofpeopleinhousehold"];
}
echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION["firstname"];//here is....
echo "ok"
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before `session_start();`

Comment: Place session_start() before anything in the file. It requires to set headers, so it must be before any output.

Comment: what is your error??

Comment: first of all what is your file name?? What is your output??

Answer (score 1):

That is actually working.  If you look at the source code you will see the your name is echoed out.

One issue is you are missing a greater than sign at the end of your form tag.

```
</form
```

should be

```
</form>
```

Also, you need to start the session before any html.  Try this...

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$_SESSION["firstname"]= $_POST["firstname"];
$_SESSION["lastname"]= $_POST["lastname"];
$_SESSION["age"]= $_POST["age"];
$_SESSION["numberofpeopleinhousehold"]= $_POST["numberofpeopleinhousehold"];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
        <b>First Name:</b> <input name="firstname" type="text" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Last Name:</b>  <input name="lastname" type="text" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Age:</b> <input name="age" type="number" min="0" value=""></br></br>
        <b>Number of people in household:</b> <input name="numberofpeopleinhousehold" type="number" min="1"value=""></br></br>

        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SESSION["firstname"] != ""){
    echo "Welcome ",$_SESSION["firstname"];
    echo "ok";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's may look like it's working, but the session is not starting with the seession_start call where it is.

Answer (score 1):

What session_start() does is sends a cookie in the page header when it's served to the browser. If you've already send some data to the browser, like your form, then PHP will not be able to start a session. You need to move `session_atart()` to the very top of your document, above the form or any `echo`s. Also, you're missing a semi-colon, as noted by others. Also, you need to properly close your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Although this might not bee the exact answer the OP was looking for, I moved my session_start to the very top, and it worked! (Yes, the other answers said this, but this one had nothing but this solution)

`<?php session_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 1):

echo output inside if, delcare session start on top, tested and works 100%. Note- add php code on top  and close form tag

```
<?php
session_start();  //session start must be first line

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $_SESSION["firstname"]= $_POST["firstname"];
    $_SESSION["lastname"]= $_POST["lastname"];
    $_SESSION["age"]= $_POST["age"];
    $_SESSION["numberofpeopleinhousehold"]=  $_POST["numberofpeopleinhousehold"];
    echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION["firstname"];  //inside if condition
    echo "ok";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <b>First Name:</b> <input name="firstname" type="text" value=""/></br></br>
    <b>Last Name:</b>  <input name="lastname" type="text" value=""/></br></br>
    <b>Age:</b> <input name="age" type="number" min="0" value=""/></br></br>
    <b>Number of people in household:</b> <input name="numberofpeopleinhousehold" type="number" min="1"value=""/></br></br>

    </br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>  <!-- close form tag -->

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `[![<?php` that's new.

Comment: Can you explain me the role behind trailing slashes between superglobal's names and it's array key ID brackets?

Comment: Just for reference, `session_start()` does not have to be the first line of you code, **but** it must be run before any other _non header_ output is made to the the browser.